# I wrote my plugin. How to display the result of the plugin's function to sidebar (widget?)?

Tags: plugins, widgets, html

I wrote my plugin. How to display the result of the plugin's function to sidebar (widget?)?

```
<?
function register_form () {
    global $post;
    $test = "testesttest";
    var_dump("testtest");
    return $test;
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'register_form' );
?>
```

How to display the sidebar this text via the admin panel of wordpress? get it done through a widget? need to create a widget?

Comment: Look at the [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) and create your own custom widget :-)

Answer (score 2):

I got the following tutorial a very good start for a widget creation:

- [**How to Create a Custom WP Widget**](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/) — WPBeginner

And I used the tutorial and made my own first widget for my plugin. You can get all my code [here in Github](https://github.com/nanodesigns/ad-zonia/blob/master/wp-adzonia.php#L280).